# Reply Link on Comments Broken in wordpress comment_reply_link()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, yoast, wordpress-plugin-creation

I use `comment_reply_link()` function to create reply comment link but the created link is broken

the script I use:

```
<?php
$argsComment = array(
   'reply_text' => '<img src="'. get_site_url() .'/wp-content/themes/webranko/img/SVG/reply.svg" alt="">',
    'depth' => 1,
    'max_depth' => 2,
);

comment_reply_link( $argsComment, $comment, $post->ID ); ?>
```

it's created this link:

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link reply replyToThisComment" href="#comment-8" data-commentid="8" data-postid="239" data-belowelement="comment-8" data-respondelement="respond" aria-label="replay to Admin" data-target="c_232">
    <img src="http://my-site.com/wp-content/themes/webranko/img/SVG/reply.svg" alt="">
</a>
```

href attribute should be a link not comment id `href="#comment-8"`

**I make a few changes, I disable Yoast SEO Premium plugin and the replay link its work but when I activate it's broke the link**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 7 of Yoast removes the `replytocom` variables by default.
You Should add the Code in your `functions.php` file

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_remove_reply_to_com', '__return_false' );
```